# Route won't match

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

### The App

I have a view that holds a list of clients, for a given company if CoId is specified, else, all the registered clients appear in the list.  The HanlderId just represents who is handling the client.  The list is paged (hence the page parameter) and sorted, hence sortField and sortDir in the code that follows.  Everything works, EXCEPT for the routes.  So...

### Setup

I have an area Registration file with the following route:

```
context.MapRoute(
                "Companies_Clients",
                "Companies/Clients/Page/{page}/{sortField}/{sortDir}/{HandlerId}/{CoId}",
                new
                {
                    controller = "MyController",
                    action = "Index", 
                    CoId = -1,
                    HandlerId = -1, 
                    page = 1, 
                    sortField = "ClaimId",
                    sortDir = "ASC", 
                    AccidentDate = UrlParameter.Optional,
                    DateOfBirth = UrlParameter.Optional,
                    ClientSurname = UrlParameter.Optional,
                    InvoiceNumber = UrlParameter.Optional
                }
            );
```

The parameters that default to UrlParameter.Optional are search parameters (the list can be searched too).

I have an action in MyController defined as follows:

```
public virtual ActionResult Index(
    Nullable<int> FeId = -1, 
    Nullable<DateTime> AccidentDate = null, 
    Nullable<DateTime> DateOfBirth = null,
    string ClientSurname = null,
    Nullable<int> InvoiceNumber = null, 
    int page = 1, string sortField = "ClaimId", string sortDir = "DESC", int SolicitorId = -1)
{
    var model = service.BuildModel(FeId, AccidentDate, DateOfBirth, ClientSurname, InvoiceNumber, page, sortField, sortDir, SolId);
    return View("Index", model);
}
```

I want all calls to Index to match my "Companies_Clients" route.

### Problem

The resulting urls from @Html.ActionLink helper calls (see next code block) DON'T match the "Companies_Clients" route.

```
//This creates a link with a url that matches the default route (the usual one)
@Html.ActionLink("Sort by Client Name", MVC.MyArea.MyController.Index(feId, accidentDate, dateOfBirth, clientSurname, invoiceNumber, currentPage, "ClientSurname", "DESC"))
```

What does, sort of, match the route is my mvcSiteMap node:

```
<mvcSiteMapNode title="Clients" area="Companies" controller="MyController" action="Index" key="clients">
```

Ie, the route this mvcsitemap node generates is:

```
/Companies/Clients/Page
```

### Question

The trivial question is:

**What am I doing wrong??  Why aren't the Html.ActionLink calls matching the route??**

The other question is:

Why don't the default parameters appear in the route generated by the mvcsitemapnode?

Comment: I would thoroughly recommend checking out phil haacks route debugger if not already using it. Its saved me a lot of headaches. http://haacked.com/archive/2008/03/13/url-routing-debugger.aspx

Comment: I use it all the time.  I can see no reason why the route isn't matched.